# Ajax query to populate warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and Ajax. I am trying to create a ajax query to populate 1 of 3 messages (High risk, Medium Risk and No Risk) in a  when an Int is entered.

My JSON:

```
public JsonResult warningsIOPLeft(int IOPLeft)
{
    string Warning = null;

    if (IOPLeft >= 20)
    {
        Warning = "High Risk";

        return Json(Warning);
    }
    else if ((IOPLeft >= 18) && (IOPLeft <= 19))
    {
        Warning = "Medium Risk";

        return Json(Warning);
    }
    else
    {
        Warning = "No Risk";

        return Json(Warning);
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IOPLeft, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IOPLeft, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IOPLeft, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="divStatus">

    </div>

@section scripts
{

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#IOPLeft").keyup(function () {
    var iOPLeft = $("#IOPLeft").val(); //Value entered in the text box
    var status = $("#divStatus"); //DIV object to display the status message
    var dataEntered = $.trim(iOPLeft);
    if (dataEntered.length > 1) {

        $.post("/Appointment/warningsIOPLeft",
                    function (Warning) {
                        if (Warning == "High Risk") {
                            status.html("<font color=red>'<b>" + Warning + "</b>' is available!</font>");
                        } else if (Warning == "Medium Risk") {
                            status.html("<font color=orange>'<b>" + Warning + "</b>' is not available!</font>");
                        } else {
                            status.html("<font color=green>'<b>" + Warning + "</b>' is not available!</font>");
                        }
                    });
    } else {
        status.html("Need more characters...");
    }
});
</script>
```

However nothing populates when I enter an int in IOPLeft and no error is displayed on the console. I'm very new to jquery and ajax so any advice where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You method `warningsIOPLeft()` has a parameter `int IOPLeft` but you never pass a value to the method (at best it will only ever return `"No Risk"`

Comment: @stephenmuecke I've added in $.post("/Appointment/warningsIOPLeft",{iOPLeft : IOPLeft} However when I enter an Int "Need more chracters is displayed"

Comment: what does console.log(Warning) returns?

Comment: @coto2, You have `if (dataEntered.length > 1)` which means the value needs to be `10` or greater. I suspect you really want `if (dataEntered.length > 0)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed it but nothing populates at all. It does run very slow however

Comment: Not surprising when you use `.keyup()` - try with `.change()` instead. But why not just do all this on the client (hardly seems necessary to call the server to do this this calculation)

Comment: Do not use font tags.

Answer (score 0):

You do not send up anything to the server, you are just posting to the server. jQuery does not magically post up the form to the server. You need to submit the values.

```
jQuery.post( url, data, success )
                 ^^^^^^
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post(
    "/Appointment/warningsIOPLeft",  //url
    { IOPLeft : dataEntered },       //data
    function (response) {            //success
        console.log(response);
    }
).fail( function() {                 //error
    console.log(arguments);
} );
```